# CSS layout problem with borders

Tags: html, css, border, fluid

I'm currently working in the following site for a client http://minta.jvsoftware.com/ but I'm trying to make the top and bottom borders of the main container `div` to look like this http://awesomescreenshot.com/0f8jdwn71 basically make the borders span to the left up to the end of the screen (don't mind the red color this is supposed to be the same color as the border I have now).

I've been trying to come up with a solution but so far I have failed, I'm willing to try a JS/jQuery solution if implementing it with just css becomes too hard.

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you probably should review your markup structure. If you want to extend that particular div to the right, you'll need padding and positioning that isn't a float. As far as I can see anyway.

Comment: If you can put the structure on jsfiddle.net, i might be able to do that for you.

Comment: Hi Samir this is basically what I got http://jsfiddle.net/KwYMU/ what I need is that the top and bottom borders "strech" all the way to the left of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by pure CSS with negative margins.

First you have to update the CSS for .container as follows:

```
.container {
  clear: both;
  font-family: "Times New Roman",Times,serif;
  margin: 124px auto 36px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 940px;
}
```

Now wrap the content of the main div into another div and apply some css like this:

```
<div id="main" class="container clearfix" role="main">
    <div style="border: 1px solid red; margin-left: -2000px; padding: 8px 8px 8px 2000px;">
        <div class="content"> ... </div>
        <div class="featured-image"> ... </div>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here a screenshot to help you figure it out:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your input, I'll try that and let you know

Comment: Great it worked! Although I assume that if the resolution is wide enough the borders won't get all the way to the left since your using 2000px but it should be good for now :)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the layout you want, i think you have to put a at the left beside the container div and make them float left and give this div the border at the top and the bottom with the red color

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use "position:absolute"? In this case it's perfect solution I guess.

```
<style>
.topborder,
.bottomborder {
  position:absolute;
  left:-100px;
  width:150px;
  height:3px;
  background:#ff0000;
  z-index:999;
}

.topborder {
  top:-3px;
}

.bottomborder {
  bottom:-3px;
}

#main {
  position:relative;
}
</style>

<div id="main" class="container clearfix" role="main">
  <div class="topborder"></div><div class="bottomborder"></div>

  your content

</div>
```

Comment: I can't do this since depending on the screen resolution I don't know how much space there will be on available on the left side